# Rails text_field object_name with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, arguments, textfield

How to pass arguments through text_field form helper.

Eg.:

```
<%= f.text_field :title(@language), class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Item Title' %>
```

Result:

```
syntax error, unexpected '(',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Item Title' %>
```

Comment: Im not setting the value of the title object, I need to pass the language parameter for the title method return the title in the language especified

Comment: @ViniciusFontoura i updated my answer, please check it again

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pass data to make your text_field display it in the placeholder, you can:

```
<%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: @language.your_class_method %>
```

Note here that the first parameter of the form helper is the attribute of the model you want to fill.
If you want to display the placeholder in a different language, you need to use as I mentioned, and make sure `your_class_method` properly transform the placeholder in the language needed.

If you are trying to pass additional information through the form to the controller, you can use an additional hidden field like:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :title, @language.your_class_method %>
```

Hope this helps!

If not, provide more information about *"passing arguments through text_field form helper"* because I'm not sure if I got that right.